# How to add an icon in front of every VuetifyJS combobox entry?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I'm using the [combobox component of VuetifyJS](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox) and I need to add an icon in front of every entry in the drop down. How to do that?
Here is a CodePen example of the combobox: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBLXYO`

HTML

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-combobox
            v-model="select"
            :items="items"
            label="Select a favorite activity or create a new one"
          ></v-combobox>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      select: 'Programming',
      items: [
        'Programming',
        'Design',
        'Vue',
        'Vuetify'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `item` scoped slot.

```
<v-combobox
  v-model="select"
  :items="items"
  label="Select a favorite activity or create a new one">

  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    <v-icon>home</v-icon>  {{data.item}}
  </template>

</v-combobox>
```

Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qyGpPG?editors=1010).

FWIW, this is all covered [in the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox).